# What happens after killing the Stalker on warframe

Tags: warframe

I have one question. does anyone know if anything special happens if you instakill the Stalker because I did that and I got the Bow from him but the next time I had a Stalker like experience is after killing the raptor boss with 3 friends.

After that I got marked for death but this time it wasn't the stalker it was 4 or 5 drones that came out from the ground and I died in seconds of them spawning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was not a Stalker attack, but by a death squad from one of the [Syndicates](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Syndicates). These death squads have nothing to do with the Stalker and they also do not drop Stalker loot.

You get targeted by death squads when you have negative standing with them.

Regarding if anything special happens if you manage to instantly kill the Stalker: No

There is (as of yet) no special reward if you kill him quick.

Comment: Ok that explains everything. do you know if it's possible to be on the good side of all the syndicates or would that make things too easy

Comment: It is possible, but that requires some serious effort. It's definitely not worth it. If you can't beat a death squad, you can just run away, but there is no running from the Stalker (he looks the room you are in until you beat him or vice versa).

Comment: It's fairly easy to get good standing with four of them at the expense of being /completely/ in the crapper with the other two, I think.

Comment: @Shadur yes you are right. It even describes how to do it on the Warframe syndicate wiki page. The process looks pretty straightforward.